# Pytest getting an empty dataframe when is not empty in conftest

Tags: python, pytest

I'm working with **pytest** and when debugging a test on VsCode, for some weird reason the `input_pandas` I create in `conftest.py` is appearing with the correct columns but is empty and that is making the test fail every time I execute it.

Any ideas T-T?

This is my `conftest.py` data:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def input_pandas():
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "user_id": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
            "product_id": [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3],
            "rating": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
            "flag": [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
            "group": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
            "rating_prediction": [2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
            "flag_prediction": [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            "flag_prediction_score": [0.3, 0.9, 0.7, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8, 0.1, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2],
        }
    )
```

And this test:

```
def test_compute_roc_curve(input_pandas):
    output_df = classification.compute_roc_curve(
        data=input_pandas,
        target_col_name="flag",
        prediction_proba_suffix="_prediction_score",
        split_col_name="split",
        calculate_all_records_ind=True,
    )
```

Gets the sklearn `roc_curve` error: `FAILED reporting_metrics/v0/tests/unit/performance/test_classification.py::test_compute_roc_curve - ValueError: y_true takes value in {} and pos_label is not specified: either make y_true take value in {0, 1} or {-1, 1} or pass pos_label explicitly.`

And that happens because the data of the test function used for some reason its empty, when it shouldn't.